# self copy c++ executable to user's drive

Tags: c++

I am trying to self copy c++ executable  to user's drive while the executable  is running , but after that I want to display it like this `std::cout << "Filepath:" << actualpath[i];` however I got filename iteration for every charcter , but I need to copy self program to another place

```c
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TCHAR szEXEPath[MAX_PATH];
    char actualpath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szEXEPath, MAX_PATH);

    for (int i = 0; szEXEPath[i] != 0; i++){
        actualpath[i] = szEXEPath[i];
        std::cout << "Filepath:" << actualpath[i];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [GetModuleFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea) is probably not doing what you expect, check MSDN. Also, try functions from `string.h` instead of looping.

Comment: and don't use `TCHAR`. Any new programs must use the Unicode API instead of choosing depending on the `UNICODE` macro. Besides, stop using Hungarian notation like `szEXEPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the line

```
std::cout << "Filepath:" << actualpath[i];
```

to be after the `for` loop. However, you have to:

1. Terminate `actualpath` with the null character.
2. In order to do that you have to know the last value of `i`. You can define `i` before the `for` loop to be able use it to null terminate `actualpath`.

```
int i = 0;
for ( ; szEXEPath[i] != 0; i++ ){
    actualpath[i] = szEXEPath[i];
}

actualpath[i] = '\0';
std::cout << "Filepath:" << actualpath;
```

**PS** This, obviously, doesn't address the main task -- copying the file.

Comment: so in this case it will be remove the \0

Comment: @victor_angel27, I didn't follow.

Comment: Just use `(std::)str(n)cpy()` instead of a manual loop: `strcpy(actualpath, szEXEPath);`.  Or better, make `actualpath` be a `std::string`: `std::string actualpath = szEXEPath;`